# How to play the video file in the front end page in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, file-upload

I able to upload the file and store the  path in the database and file in media folder .but when i try to play the file its not playing the video please help me out to play the file .

my controller:

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            include("lib/imageManipulation.php");
            include("lib/resize-class.php");
            $path=$_FILES['file']['name'];
            $pathmedia=$_FILES['multimedia_path']['name'];
                $type       =   pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $type2=pathinfo($pathmedia,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $img_name   = date('hhmmss');
                $img_name   =   str_replace(" ","_",$img_name);
                $media_name     =str_replace(" ","_",$img_name);
                $big_image  =   "assets/img/".$img_name.".".$type;
                $media  =   "assets/media/".$img_name.".".$type2;
                copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$media );/** this is used to move the file to my folder */
                copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$big_image );
                $resizeObj = new resize($big_image);
                $resizeObj -> resizeImage(220, 220, 'auto');
                $resizeObj -> saveImage($big_image, 100);

                $data_to_store = array(
                'recording_id' => $this->input->post(''),
                'title' => $this->input->post('title'),

                'image_path'=>$big_image ,
                'multimedia_path'=>$media ,
               );//if the insert has returned t
            //if the insert has returned true then we show the flash message
            $this->load->model('Admin_model');
            if($this->Admin_model->storerecord($data_to_store))
            {
                $data['flash_message'] = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                $data['flash_message'] = FALSE;
            }
            header("Location:".  base_url()."index.php/Admin/displayrecord");
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('admin/recording/addrecord');
```

view:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="<?php echo base_url().$recording->multimedia_path; ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Did you check if this <?php echo base_url().$recording->multimedia_path; ?> output an url?

Comment: yes it will display the right file name but not playing the file

Comment: it shows like this http://localhost/my_root/assets/img/090911112626.mp4

Comment: I know it might be a trivial question for you, but did you check all the common mistakes such as checking the format of the video being correct and downloading the video manually and checking that the video itself is playing correctly?

Comment: its showing any error

Comment: yes i have checked wen i m uploading the file i just got to know my image file is oly converting in media file.please can u tell me solution for it  @ hoijof

Comment: no it don't show any error @ mahit

Comment: does your browser support that files codec?

Comment: yes it will support it will play the file but not media file  it plays the image which i have uploaded with it.